# An error occured while the tag was fired: net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-ads-api

I am using google adword tag in my project.

I have placed all the adword data in a separate js plugin file which looks like below:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn._djconversion = function (options) {
        var _self = this;
        //--default options
        var opts = $.extend({
            google_conversion_id: 981680506,
            google_conversion_language: "en",
            google_conversion_format: "3",
            google_conversion_color: "ffffff",
            google_conversion_label: "aPTpCKjOu2wQ-oKN1AM",
            google_remarketing_only: false
        }, options);
        //--init function
        _self.init(function () {

            $.getScript('//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js');

            var image = new Image(1, 1);
            image.src = "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/" + opts.google_conversion_id + "/?label=" + opts.google_conversion_label + "&guid=ON&script=0";
            /* Conversion Tracking End */
        });
        _self.init();
        //make the plugin chainnable with other methods
        return _self;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now we call the method on a button click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){
        var gopts = {
            google_conversion_label: "aPTpCKjOu2wQ-oKN1AM"
        };
        $("body")._djconversion(gopts);
});
```